# Where in the world do Stack Overflow users say they are from?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users, statistics, faq-proposed

I wanted to know more about [where in the world Stack Overflow users come from](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-come-from).

Is there any way I could get more data for this?
Are there any more maps or charts to further identify where users are coming from across the world?
How could I go about generating my own maps or charts?

---

***Note:** The original statistics and images provided with this question in 2009 are available in the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/25598/8).*

Comment: What about if we add [tag:internationalization] to this question? Perhaps use it to replace [tag:faq-proposed].

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I ran [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/139228/171156/user-count-by-location) to gather data on all Stack Overflow users with over 1000 reputation.

That got a total of 4,711 unique locations for 48,924 users. Of those 48,924 users, 13,138 did not list a location. Of the remaining 35,786 users, I manually inputted the country for 28,490 (almost 80%), which is the 437 most input locations, and also all locations with over 10 users reporting it.

In the spirit of the original, I generated both the raw user count, and the per capita (using population data from [Gap Minder](http://gapminder.org/) which I already had compiled elsewhere).

## Top 10 Lists

### By User Count

1. United States (9,592)
2. United Kingdom (2,906)
3. India (2,005)
4. Germany (1,461)
5. Canada (1,397)
6. Australia (1,260)
7. France (724)
8. Sweden (637)
9. Russian Federation (447)
10. Poland (439)

### By Per Capita Usage (per million population)

1. New Zealand (70.8)
2. Sweden (70.4)
3. Australia (61.2)
4. Norway (58.3)
5. Israel (57.7)
6. Ireland (48.1)
7. United Kingdom (47.7)
8. Denmark (47.2)
9. Switzerland (45.4)
10. Estonia (42.8)

## World by User Count

[image: World by User Count]

## World by Per Capita Users

[image: World by Per Capita Users]

## Europe by User Count

[image: Europe by User Count]

<sup>Note: This map uses the same color scale as the world map</sup>

## Europe by Per Capita Users

[image: Europe by Per Capita Users]

<sup>Note: This map uses the same color scale as the world map</sup>

## Asia by User Count

[image: Asia by User Count]

<sup>Note: This map uses the same color scale as the world map</sup>

## Asia by Per Capita Users

[image: Asia by Per Capita Users]

<sup>Note: This map uses the same color scale as the world map</sup>

> Note: The following charts are done through automatic searching of state abbreviations and names from the full data set of over 1000 users. It is therefore prone to errors. It is also set on a different scale.

## State by User Count

[image: State by User Count]

## State by Per Capita Users

[image: State by Per Capita Users]

The following code will create a [google geochart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_chart) of the data with some interactivity. To figure out how to play with it, feel free to check out [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization) (I hear folks are helpful over in that tag):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Users');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Users per Capita');
  data.addRows([
    [{v:'AR', f:'Argentina'}, 124, 3],
    [{v:'AM', f:'Armenia'}, 13, 4.4],
    [{v:'AU', f:'Australia'}, 1260, 61.2],
    [{v:'AT', f:'Austria'}, 102, 12.4],
    [{v:'BD', f:'Bangladesh'}, 57, 0.4],
    [{v:'BY', f:'Belarus'}, 95, 9.2],
    [{v:'BE', f:'Belgium'}, 321, 30.9],
    [{v:'BA', f:'Bosnia and Herzegovina'}, 10, 2.2],
    [{v:'BR', f:'Brazil'}, 297, 1.5],
    [{v:'BG', f:'Bulgaria'}, 98, 13.5],
    [{v:'CA', f:'Canada'}, 1397, 41.5],
    [{v:'CL', f:'Chile'}, 20, 1.2],
    [{v:'CN', f:'China'}, 184, 0.1],
    [{v:'CO', f:'Colombia'}, 13, 0.3],
    [{v:'HR', f:'Croatia'}, 69, 15.4],
    [{v:'CZ', f:'Czech Republic'}, 194, 19],
    [{v:'DK', f:'Denmark'}, 259, 47.2],
    [{v:'EG', f:'Egypt'}, 53, 0.6],
    [{v:'EE', f:'Estonia'}, 56, 42.8],
    [{v:'FI', f:'Finland'}, 179, 34.1],
    [{v:'FR', f:'France'}, 724, 11.8],
    [{v:'GE', f:'Georgia'}, 33, 7.1],
    [{v:'DE', f:'Germany'}, 1461, 17.7],
    [{v:'GR', f:'Greece'}, 97, 9],
    [{v:'HU', f:'Hungary'}, 121, 12.2],
    [{v:'IS', f:'Iceland'}, 13, 42.7],
    [{v:'IN', f:'India'}, 2005, 1.8],
    [{v:'ID', f:'Indonesia'}, 36, 0.2],
    [{v:'IR', f:'Iran, Islamic Republic of'}, 70, 1],
    [{v:'IE', f:'Ireland'}, 200, 48.1],
    [{v:'IL', f:'Israel'}, 375, 57.7],
    [{v:'IT', f:'Italy'}, 317, 5.5],
    [{v:'JP', f:'Japan'}, 108, 0.8],
    [{v:'JO', f:'Jordan'}, 13, 2.1],
    [{v:'KR', f:'Korea, Republic of'}, 28, 0.6],
    [{v:'LV', f:'Latvia'}, 49, 21.8],
    [{v:'LB', f:'Lebanon'}, 23, 5.8],
    [{v:'LT', f:'Lithuania'}, 50, 14],
    [{v:'MK', f:'Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of'}, 11, 5.3],
    [{v:'MY', f:'Malaysia'}, 34, 1.3],
    [{v:'MT', f:'Malta'}, 16, 39.6],
    [{v:'MX', f:'Mexico'}, 51, 0.5],
    [{v:'NP', f:'Nepal'}, 36, 1.2],
    [{v:'NZ', f:'New Zealand'}, 294, 70.8],
    [{v:'NO', f:'Norway'}, 271, 58.3],
    [{v:'PK', f:'Pakistan'}, 144, 0.8],
    [{v:'PE', f:'Peru'}, 12, 0.4],
    [{v:'PH', f:'Philippines'}, 79, 0.9],
    [{v:'PL', f:'Poland'}, 439, 11.4],
    [{v:'PT', f:'Portugal'}, 78, 7.3],
    [{v:'RO', f:'Romania'}, 221, 9.9],
    [{v:'RU', f:'Russian Federation'}, 447, 3.2],
    [{v:'RS', f:'Serbia'}, 65, 6.4],
    [{v:'SG', f:'Singapore'}, 137, 29.7],
    [{v:'SK', f:'Slovakia'}, 61, 11.2],
    [{v:'SI', f:'Slovenia'}, 63, 31.4],
    [{v:'ZA', f:'South Africa'}, 187, 4.3],
    [{v:'ES', f:'Spain'}, 254, 6.3],
    [{v:'LK', f:'Sri Lanka'}, 59, 2.9],
    [{v:'SE', f:'Sweden'}, 637, 70.4],
    [{v:'CH', f:'Switzerland'}, 344, 45.4],
    [{v:'TW', f:'Taiwan, Province of China'}, 28, 1.2],
    [{v:'TH', f:'Thailand'}, 34, 0.5],
    [{v:'TR', f:'Turkey'}, 138, 1.9],
    [{v:'UA', f:'Ukraine'}, 256, 5.5],
    [{v:'AE', f:'United Arab Emirates'}, 16, 6],
    [{v:'GB', f:'United Kingdom'}, 2906, 47.7],
    [{v:'US', f:'United States'}, 9592, 31.6],
    [{v:'UY', f:'Uruguay'}, 29, 8.4],
    [{v:'VE', f:'Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of'}, 12, 0.5],
    [{v:'VN', f:'Viet Nam'}, 23, 0.3],
  ]);

  var dataUS = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataUS.addColumn('string', 'State');
  dataUS.addColumn('number', 'Users');
  dataUS.addColumn('number', 'Users per Capita');
  dataUS.addRows([
    [{v:'AL', f:'Alabama'}, 74, 15.3],
    [{v:'AK', f:'Alaska'}, 24, 32.8],
    [{v:'AZ', f:'Arizona'}, 171, 26.1],
    [{v:'AR', f:'Arkansas'}, 30, 10.2],
    [{v:'CA', f:'California'}, 2213, 58.2],
    [{v:'CO', f:'Colorado'}, 346, 66.7],
    [{v:'CT', f:'Connecticut'}, 84, 23.4],
    [{v:'DE', f:'Delaware'}, 36, 39.3],
    [{v:'FL', f:'Florida'}, 384, 19.9],
    [{v:'GA', f:'Georgia'}, 217, 21.9],
    [{v:'HI', f:'Hawaii'}, 20, 14.4],
    [{v:'ID', f:'Idaho'}, 49, 30.7],
    [{v:'IL', f:'Illinois'}, 369, 28.7],
    [{v:'IN', f:'Indiana'}, 172, 26.3],
    [{v:'IA', f:'Iowa'}, 73, 23.7],
    [{v:'KS', f:'Kansas'}, 120, 41.6],
    [{v:'KY', f:'Kentucky'}, 59, 13.5],
    [{v:'LA', f:'Louisiana'}, 31, 6.7],
    [{v:'ME', f:'Maine'}, 31, 23.3],
    [{v:'MD', f:'Maryland'}, 180, 30.6],
    [{v:'MA', f:'Massachusetts'}, 480, 72.2],
    [{v:'MI', f:'Michigan'}, 220, 22.3],
    [{v:'MN', f:'Minnesota'}, 215, 40],
    [{v:'MS', f:'Mississippi'}, 17, 5.7],
    [{v:'MO', f:'Missouri'}, 147, 24.4],
    [{v:'MT', f:'Montana'}, 20, 19.9],
    [{v:'NE', f:'Nebraska'}, 55, 29.6],
    [{v:'NV', f:'Nevada'}, 44, 15.9],
    [{v:'NH', f:'New Hampshire'}, 56, 42.4],
    [{v:'NJ', f:'New Jersey'}, 169, 19.1],
    [{v:'NM', f:'New Mexico'}, 28, 13.4],
    [{v:'NY', f:'New York'}, 1323, 67.6],
    [{v:'NC', f:'North Carolina'}, 245, 25.1],
    [{v:'ND', f:'North Dakota'}, 8, 11.4],
    [{v:'OH', f:'Ohio'}, 269, 23.3],
    [{v:'OK', f:'Oklahoma'}, 69, 18.1],
    [{v:'OR', f:'Oregon'}, 275, 70.5],
    [{v:'PA', f:'Pennsylvania'}, 379, 29.7],
    [{v:'RI', f:'Rhode Island'}, 24, 22.9],
    [{v:'SC', f:'South Carolina'}, 68, 14.4],
    [{v:'SD', f:'South Dakota'}, 16, 19.2],
    [{v:'TN', f:'Tennessee'}, 103, 16],
    [{v:'TX', f:'Texas'}, 663, 25.4],
    [{v:'UT', f:'Utah'}, 206, 72.1],
    [{v:'VT', f:'Vermont'}, 22, 35.1],
    [{v:'VA', f:'Virginia'}, 294, 35.9],
    [{v:'WA', f:'Washington'}, 859, 124.5],
    [{v:'WV', f:'West Virginia'}, 15, 8.1],
    [{v:'WI', f:'Wisconsin'}, 178, 31.1],
    [{v:'WY', f:'Wyoming'}, 6, 10.4],
    [{v:'DC', f:'District of Columbia'}, 106, 167.6],
  ]);

  
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  
  // Set columns to [0,2] for Per Capita, [0,1] for Count
  
  view.setColumns([0,2]);

  var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geochart.draw(view, {
    backgroundColor: '#E5E5FF',
    datalessRegionColor: '#FFFFFF',
 
    // UN Region Codes, 142: Asia, 150: Europe, 021: North America, comment out for world view
    
    region: '142',
    width: 800,
    //height: 600,
    colorAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      
      // Set to 70 for per capita, 10,000 for count
      
      maxValue: 70,
      
      // This is the range for min color code to max color code
      
      colors: ['#AAAAAA', '#000000']},
  });
}
```

<sup>Disclaimer: There may be errors and stuff. Probably are. C'est la vie. Probably not indicative of where actual users unless users who do not share location are distributed the same as the users who do share location which I would find unlikely due to national identity and privacy concerns. This is only for SO, not for SU or the other sites. Your mileage may vary. Void where prohibited by law. Only valid in the continental 48 states. Speaking of states, I didn't even take a shot at recording users by state in the US. Sorry! But you can give it a shot.</sup>

## Data Dump:

For the sake of those who may want to geocode in the future, here are the associations between the locations I hand-coded and the locations entered by users. All country codes are ISO-3166 alpha-2:

> <sup>'United States', 'US';'United Kingdom', 'GB';'London, United
> Kingdom', 'GB';'Germany', 'DE';'India', 'IN';'San Francisco, CA',
> 'US';'Netherlands', 'ND';'Seattle, WA', 'US';'New York, NY',
> 'US';'California', 'US';'Bangalore, India', 'IN';'Israel',
> 'IL';'Canada', 'CA';'France', 'FR';'Sydney, Australia', 'AU';'Sweden',
> 'SE';'Australia', 'AU';'Toronto, Canada', 'CA';'Paris, France',
> 'FR';'Melbourne, Australia', 'AU';'Chicago, IL', 'US';'Berlin,
> Germany', 'DE';'Boston, MA', 'US';'Belgium', 'BE';'Austin, TX',
> 'US';'Switzerland', 'CH';'Poland', 'PL';'Italy', 'IT';'Moscow,
> Russia', 'RU';'Montreal, Canada', 'CA';'Stockholm, Sweden', 'SE';'New
> York, United States', 'US';'Brazil', 'BR';'Los Angeles, CA',
> 'US';'England, United Kingdom', 'UK';'Vancouver, Canada',
> 'CA';'Denmark', 'DK';'Portland, OR', 'US';'New Zealand',
> 'NZ';'Russia', 'RU';'Atlanta, GA', 'US';'Pune, India', 'IN';'Chennai,
> India', 'IN';'San Diego, CA', 'US';'Munich, Germany', 'DE';'Brisbane,
> Australia', 'AU';'Mumbai, India', 'IN';'Ukraine', 'UA';'Norway',
> 'NO';'Finland', 'FI';'South Africa', 'ZA';'Denver, CO',
> 'US';'Brooklyn, NY', 'US';'New Jersey', 'US';'Oslo, Norway',
> 'NO';'Dallas, TX', 'US';'Redmond, WA', 'US';'Dublin, Ireland',
> 'IE';'Philadelphia, PA', 'US';'Minneapolis, MN', 'US';'Pittsburgh,
> PA', 'US';'Vienna, Austria', 'AU';'Spain', 'ES';'Houston, TX',
> 'US';'Cambridge, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Mountain View, CA',
> 'US';'Ireland', 'IE';'Warsaw, Poland', 'PL';'Washington, DC',
> 'US';'Florida', 'US';'Ahmadabad, India', 'IN';'Prague, Czech
> Republic', 'CZ';'Austria', 'AT';'Hyderabad, India', 'IN';'San Jose,
> CA', 'US';'Manchester, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Bucharest, Romania',
> 'RO';'Ottawa, Canada', 'CA';'Boulder, CO', 'US';'St. Petersburg,
> Russia', 'RU';'Amsterdam, Netherlands', 'ND';'Auckland, New Zealand',
> 'NZ';'Istanbul, Turkey', 'TR';'Massachusetts', 'US';'Czech Republic',
> 'CZ';'Hamburg, Germany', 'DE';'Virginia', 'US';'Phoenix, AZ',
> 'US';'Utah', 'US';'Copenhagen, Denmark', 'DK';'Romania',
> 'RO';'Budapest, Hungary', 'HU';'Madrid, Spain', 'ES';'Barcelona,
> Spain', 'ES';'Singapore', 'SG';'Michigan', 'US';'Texas', 'US';'Tokyo,
> Japan', 'JP';'Kiev, Ukraine', 'UA';'Minnesota', 'US';'Buenos Aires,
> Argentina', 'AR';'Zurich, Switzerland', 'CH';'Europe', 'null';'Perth,
> Australia', 'AU';'Portugal', 'PT';'Philippines', 'PH';'Minsk,
> Belarus', 'BY';'Singapore, Singapore', 'SG';'Maryland', 'US';'Ohio',
> 'US';'Pennsylvania', 'US';'Columbus, OH', 'US';'London',
> 'GB';'Calgary, Canada', 'CA';'Edinburgh, United Kingdom',
> 'GB';'Earth', 'null';'Gothenburg, Sweden', 'SE';'Cambridge, MA',
> 'US';'Colorado', 'US';'Palo Alto, CA', 'US';'Salt Lake City, UT',
> 'US';'Baltimore, MD', 'US';'North Carolina', 'US';'Sofia, Bulgaria',
> 'BG';'Argentina', 'AR';'Bristol, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Wisconsin',
> 'US';'Raleigh, NC', 'US';'England', 'GB';'UK', 'GB';'Rochester, NY',
> 'US';'St Louis, MO', 'US';'Hungary', 'HU';'China', 'CN';'Lahore,
> Pakistan', 'PK';'Milan, Italy', 'IT';'Pakistan', 'PK';'Brussels,
> Belgium', 'BE';'New Delhi, India', 'IN';'Waterloo, Canada',
> 'CA';'Indianapolis, IN', 'US';'Shanghai, China', 'CN';'Glasgow, United
> Kingdom', 'GB';'Madison, WI', 'US';'Athens, Greece', 'GR';'Helsinki,
> Finland', 'FI';'Cape Town, South Africa', 'ZA';'Cologne, Germany',
> 'DE';'Sao Paulo, Brazil', 'BR';'Slovakia', 'SK';'Orlando, FL',
> 'US';'Nashville, TN', 'US';'Zagreb, Croatia', 'HR';'Bulgaria',
> 'BG';'Illinois', 'US';'Rome, Italy', 'IT';'Brighton, United Kingdom',
> 'GB';'London, UK', 'GB';'Cincinnati, OH', 'US';'Amsterdam, The
> Netherlands', 'ND';'Scotland, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Berkeley, CA',
> 'US';'Charlotte, NC', 'US';'Tehran, Iran', 'IR';'Tel Aviv, Israel',
> 'IL';'Greece', 'GR';'Ann Arbor, MI', 'US';'New York', 'US';'Tampa,
> FL', 'US';'Oregon', 'US';'Slovenia', 'SI';'Cleveland, OH',
> 'US';'Nottingham, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Beijing, China',
> 'CN';'Sunnyvale, CA', 'US';'Milwaukee, WI', 'US';'San Francisco Bay
> Area', 'US';'Leeds, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Sacramento, CA',
> 'US';'Japan', 'JP';'Wellington, New Zealand', 'NZ';'Kochi, India',
> 'IN';'Arizona', 'US';'Reading, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Turkey',
> 'TR';'Lyon, France', 'FR';'Mexico', 'MX';'Dhaka, Bangladesh',
> 'BD';'Egypt', 'EG';'Cluj-Napoca, Romania', 'RO';'Tallinn, Estonia',
> 'EE';'Adelaide, Australia', 'AU';'Wroclaw, Poland', 'PL';'Bellevue,
> WA', 'US';'Earth, TX', 'US';'Ontario, Canada', 'CA';'Karachi,
> Pakistan', 'PK';'Birmingham, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Colombo, Sri
> Lanka', 'LK';'Oxford, United Kingdom', 'GB';'Oakland, CA', 'US';'Las
> Vegas, NV', 'US';'Stuttgart, Germany', 'DE';'Lisbon, Portugal',
> 'PL';'USA', 'US';'Gurgaon, India', 'IN';'Richmond, VA',
> 'US';'Belarus', 'BY';'Delhi, India', 'IN';'Hong Kong', 'CN';'Kolkata,
> India', 'IN';'Noida, India', 'IN';'Connecticut', 'US';'Dresden,
> Germany', 'DE';'Belgrade, Serbia', 'RS';'Indiana', 'US';'Iran',
> 'IR';'Grand Rapids, MI', 'US';'Omaha, NE', 'US';'Victoria, Canada',
> 'CA';'Delhi', 'IN';'Edmonton, Canada', 'CA';'Miami, FL', 'US';'Irvine,
> CA', 'US';'Ghent, Belgium', 'BE';'Johannesburg, South Africa',
> 'ZA';'New Hampshire', 'US';'Sri Lanka', 'LK';'Thiruvananthapuram,
> India', 'IN';'Canberra, Australia', 'AU';'San Francisco',
> 'US';'Washington, United States', 'US';'Lithuania', 'LT';'Croatia',
> 'HR';'Karlsruhe, Germany', 'DE';'Delaware', 'US';'Utrecht,
> Netherlands', 'ND';'Serbia', 'RS';'Bremen, Germany', 'DE';'Ankara,
> Turkey', 'TR';'Brno, Czech Republic', 'CZ';'Quebec City, Canada',
> 'CA';'Eindhoven, Netherlands', 'ND';'Ljubljana, Slovenia',
> 'SI';'Arlington, VA', 'US';'Geneva, Switzerland', 'CH';'Provo, UT',
> 'US';'Jaipur, India', 'IN';'Vietnam', 'VN';'Bangladesh',
> 'BD';'Lausanne, Switzerland', 'CH';'Malmﾃｶ, Sweden', 'SE';'Huntsville,
> AL', 'US';'British Columbia, Canada', 'CA';'Kharkiv, Ukraine',
> 'UA';'Aachen, Germany', 'DE';'Estonia', 'EE';'Lviv, Ukraine',
> 'UA';'Louisville, KY', 'US';'Ahmedabad', 'IN';'Trondheim, Norway',
> 'NO';'Malaysia', 'MY';'Ahmedabad, India', 'IN';'Hong Kong, Hong Kong',
> 'CN';'Santa Clara, CA', 'US';'Bangalore', 'IN';'Southampton, United
> Kingdom', 'GB';'Poznan, Poland', 'PL';'Iowa', 'US';'Liverpool, United
> Kingdom', 'GB';'Krakow, Poland', 'PL';'Kathmandu, Nepal',
> 'NP';'Indonesia', 'ID';'Kansas City, MO', 'US';'Santiago, Chile',
> 'CL';'Riga, Republic of Latvia', 'LV';'Thailand', 'TH';'Cracow,
> Poland', 'PL';'Buffalo, NY', 'US';'Cairo, Egypt', 'EG';'Sheffield,
> United Kingdom', 'GB';'Cupertino, CA', 'US';'Belfast, United Kingdom',
> 'GB';'Lund, Sweden', 'SE';'Bonn, Germany', 'DE';'Bergen, Norway',
> 'NO';'Detroit, MI', 'US';'Christchurch, New Zealand', 'NZ';'Seoul,
> South Korea', 'KR';'St. Louis, MO', 'US';'Durham, NC',
> 'US';'Frankfurt, Germany', 'DE';'Winnipeg, Canada', 'CA';'Montevideo,
> Uruguay', 'UY';'Rio De Janeiro, Brazil', 'BR';'Kerala', 'IN';'Kansas',
> 'US';'Mexico City, Mexico', 'MX';'Halifax, Canada', 'CA';'Santa
> Barbara, CA', 'US';'Bratislava, Slovakia', 'SK';'Jacksonville, FL',
> 'US';'Tbilisi, Georgia', 'GE';'Timisoara, Romania', 'RO';'Dﾃｼsseldorf,
> Germany', 'DE';'Newcastle upon Tyne, United Kingdom',
> 'GB';'Chandigarh, India', 'IN';'Leipzig, Germany', 'DE';'Kerala,
> India', 'IN';'Colorado Springs, CO', 'US';'Des Moines, IA',
> 'US';'Knoxville, TN', 'US';'Toulouse, France', 'FR';'Riga, Latvia',
> 'LV';'Dubai, United Arab Emirates', 'AE';'Nepal', 'NP';'Cardiff,
> United Kingdom', 'GB';'Georgia', 'GE';'York, United Kingdom',
> 'GB';'Cary, NC', 'US';'Malta', 'MT';'Jakarta, Indonesia', 'ID';'Berne,
> Switzerland', 'CH';'Birmingham, AL', 'US';'Islamabad, Pakistan',
> 'PK';'Kyiv, Ukraine', 'UA';'Silicon Valley', 'US';'San Antonio, TX',
> 'US';'The Netherlands', 'ND';'Bangkok, Thailand', 'TH';'Turin, Italy',
> 'IT';'Maine', 'US';'Grenoble, France', 'FR';'Belo Horizonte, Brazil',
> 'BR';'Blacksburg, VA', 'US';'Kentucky', 'US';'Coimbatore, India',
> 'IN';'Albuquerque, NM', 'US';'Uppsala, Sweden', 'SE';'Rio de Janeiro,
> Brazil', 'BR';'Antwerp, Belgium', 'BE';'Scottsdale, AZ',
> 'US';'Oklahoma City, OK', 'US';'Alabama', 'US';'Taipei City, Taiwan',
> 'TW';'Boise, ID', 'US';'Bellingham, WA', 'US';'Fairfax, VA',
> 'US';'Tennessee', 'US';'Manila, Philippines', 'PH';'Taiwan',
> 'TW';'Santa Monica, CA', 'US';'Tucson, AZ', 'US';'Syracuse, NY',
> 'US';'Berlin', 'DE';'Missouri', 'US';'Iceland', 'IS';'Santa Cruz, CA',
> 'US';'Colombia', 'CO';'Quebec', 'CA';'Yerevan, Armenia',
> 'AM';'Campinas, Brazil', 'BR';'The Hague, The Netherlands',
> 'ND';'Kansas City, KS', 'US';'Scotland', 'GB';'Novosibirsk, Russia',
> 'RU';'NYC', 'US';'Kirkland, WA', 'US';'Vancouver, WA', 'US';'Amman,
> Jordan', 'JO';'Fort Worth, TX', 'US';'South Carolina', 'US';'Latvia',
> 'LV';'Vermont', 'US';'Iasi, Romania', 'RO';'Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia',
> 'MY';'Columbia, SC', 'US';'Bloomington, IN', 'US';'Gdansk, Poland',
> 'PL';'Overland Park, KS', 'US';'Charleston, SC', 'US';'Heidelberg,
> Germany', 'DE';'Southern California', 'US';'Vilnius, Republic of
> Lithuania', 'LT';'Kitchener, Canada', 'CA';'Uruguay', 'UY';'Porto,
> Portugal', 'PT';'Thessaloniki, Greece', 'GR';'Lima, Peru',
> 'PE';'Beirut, Lebanon', 'LB';'San Mateo, CA', 'US';'Champaign, IL',
> 'US';'Vilnius, Lithuania', 'LT';'Venezuela', 'VE';'Vadodara, India',
> 'IN';'District of Columbia', 'US';'Rotterdam, The Netherlands',
> 'ND';'Lebanon', 'LB';'Saskatoon, Canada', 'CA';'Novi Sad, Serbia',
> 'RS';'Gainesville, FL', 'US';'Macedonia', 'MK';'Rennes, France',
> 'FR';'Linkﾃｶping, Sweden', 'SE';'Bologna, Italy', 'IT';'Fort Collins,
> CO', 'US';'Honolulu, HI', 'US';'Paris', 'FR';'Strasbourg, France',
> 'FR';'St Paul, MN', 'US';'Newcastle Upon Tyne, United Kingdom',
> 'GB';'Montpellier, France', 'FR';'South Korea', 'KR';'Porto Alegre,
> Brazil', 'BR';'Washington', 'US';'Tampere, Finland', 'FI';'Idaho',
> 'US';'Hanover, Germany', 'DE';'Providence, RI', 'US';'Nebraska',
> 'US';'Plano, TX', 'US';'Memphis, TN', 'US';'ﾃ・hus, Denmark',
> 'DK';'Mississauga, Canada', 'CA';'Chapel Hill, NC', 'US';'Dayton, OH',
> 'US';'Anchorage, AK', 'US';'Nantes, France', 'FR';'Bath, United
> Kingdom', 'GB';'Lexington, KY', 'US';'Arkansas', 'US';'Tulsa, OK',
> 'US';'Barcelona', 'ES';'Lincoln, NE', 'US';'Sarajevo, Bosnia and
> Herzegovina', 'BA';'Graz, Austria', 'AT';'Quebec, Canada', 'CA';</sup>

Comment: You still haven't found Carmen Sandiego?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards She left Germany, went over to Denmark, crossed the water, went to Sweden, cut back to Wales, then up to Ireland, then she jumped into the water, swam away, and we lost her. Sorry. [source](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Carmen_Sandiego#Ripping_Off_the_Rock_.5B1.7.5D)

Comment: Mercator? My eyes!!

Comment: @AakashM Bring it up with Google! They picked mercator! Maybe they like making Greenland look fat!

Comment: Is it just me, or does the data dump look very chunky?

Comment: @Jeff It is chunky. Being a non-programmer, I did all my work in Excel. Rather than provide it on a zillion lines, I just quoted and comma separated user location and coded location, and then put a semi-colon between each entry so you can parse it with whatever language you want. If you would like it in a different format, you could upload it to Google Spreadsheets or the like to make it more accessible.

Comment: @jmac I added some more sup and sub tags to make it smaller and searchable, but it got a bit too small.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards can i upvote your comment over nine thousand times?

Comment: If you get access to the database @Hugo :-).

Comment: This is why I want to live in Sweden. One out of every 14204 people in Sweden has over 1000 reputation.

Comment: -1 No Freehand Circles!