# What countries have the most Stack Overflow users per capita?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users, statistics, demographics

This is a follow-up to [Where in the world do Stack Overflow users say they are from?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stackoverflow-users-say-they-are-from)  As [requested by Kyle Cronin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stackoverflow-users-say-they-are-from/25601#25601), I've calculated the number of Stack Overflow users per capita.  I'm making this a separate post since there were already so many charts and tables on the other one.  But, lest anyone accuse me of rep-whoring, I'm making this post CW.

I have once again provided the full data in a Google Docs spreadsheet, and it is also available in Excel format.

**Edit (2010.01.06):** My previous post had incorrect per-capita data for the states in the US. I think I pasted the population data into my spreadsheet sorted by state name, when I had sorted the data by number of users. The result was that states had the incorrect populations. I have updated the chart and the Google spreadsheet to reflect the accurate numbers. And I apologize to all the Wasingtonians (state and DC) and Delewarians I offended. :)

---

### Overview in charts

#### Worldwide

[image]

#### Europe

[image]

#### United States

[image]

### Users per capita by country (top 20)

```
Country         Users per 1,000,000 residents
---------------------------------------------
Bermuda         15.3846
Isle of Man     12.5000
New Zealand     11.0939
Norway           9.5049
Iceland          9.3971
Sweden           8.9092
United Kingdom   8.7289
Australia        8.6148
Ireland          7.4003
Malta            7.2529
Canada           7.1874
Denmark          7.0659
Israel           6.7025
United States    5.8728
Netherlands      5.7398
Finland          5.0493
Switzerland      4.5185
Slovenia         4.3967
Belgium          3.8123
Estonia          3.7302
```

### Users per capita by state/province

#### United States (top 20)

```
St/Prov                   Users per 1,000,000 residents
-------------------------------------------------------------
DC  District of Columbia  27.0347
DE  Delaware              19.4710
WA  Washington            16.3378
VT  Vermont                9.6576
MA  Massachusetts          8.1564
CO  Colorado               8.0981
OR  Oregon                 7.9154
UT  Utah                   6.5779
NY  New York               6.0543
CA  California             5.6860
MN  Minnesota              5.5551
ME  Maine                  5.3173
ID  Idaho                  5.2500
VA  Virginia               5.1486
PA  Pennsylvania           5.1413
NE  Nebraska               5.0464
AR  Arkansas               4.9030
WI  Wisconsin              4.7975
RI  Rhode Island           4.7583
MD  Maryland               4.4377
```

#### Canada

```
St/Prov                   Users per 1,000,000 residents
-------------------------------------------------------
YT  Yukon                 29.9025
PE  Prince Edward Island  21.3672
BC  British Columbia       9.5023
AB  Alberta                6.0565
ON  Ontario                5.7751
NB  New Brunswick          4.0090
SK  Saskatchewan           3.9070
NS  Nova Scotia            3.1931
QC  Quebec                 2.9553
MB  Manitoba               0.8238
```

#### United Kingdom

```
St/Prov           Users per 1,000,000 residents
-----------------------------------------------
Scotland          6.1914
England           5.3065
Wales             1.9969
Northern Ireland  1.1268
```

#### Australia

```
St/Prov                            Users per 1,000,000 residents
----------------------------------------------------------------
WA   Western Australia             7.1232
VIC  Victoria                      6.5319
NSW  New South Wales               6.0966
QLD  Queensland                    5.4996
SA   South Australia               4.4178
ACT  Australian Capital Territory  2.9420
```

*Stack Overflow data retrieved from StatOverflow sandbox on 2009-10-05 (September 2009 data dump) for users with rep >= 1000.  Population data retrieved from Wikipedia on 2009-10-13.*

### Just for TXI

[image: frhc]

Comment: wow, very interesting information

Comment: 100% of we Super Mario Landians are Stack Overflow users, you discriminating monster.

Comment: Bermuda and Isle of Man? I guess there *are* a lot of people interested in "boat programming".

Comment: Isle of Man has a lot of banking (for tax reasons), so it may have more IT people then expected.

Comment: @gnovice: @Ian Ringrose: actually if you look at the full data, only one SO user with rep >= 1000 in each of Bermuda and Isle Of Man.  But their population is so low that, per capita, they come out on top.

Comment: Illinois second in user per capita...and we could not get a Dev Days in Chicago.

Comment: I suspect people from tiny, exotic locations are *damn* proud of it.  And hence more likely to accurately fill in the location.

Comment: @Stu: ...or people from boring places like Ohio are more likely to lie about it and put Bermuda.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I think you mean the people in Wyoming.

Comment: @Stu: some of us like Wyoming.  Ohio, on the other hand...

Comment: Hey now, us Ohioans come in at a respectable 3rd among the states.

Comment: @Franks and Beans: @gnostradamus: After Pollyanna posted an answer yesterday, I looked at the data and realized the per-state data was incorrect. I've updated the post with the correct data--see the edit info at the top of this post.

Comment: @Kip: Dang! Ohio isn't even on the list anymore.

Comment: @Peter: I assume it's a temporary thing. Wait a little bit.

Comment: The "StatOverflow sandbox" link appears to be broken (403).

Comment: The figures for the UK don't seem to add up. Unless there are loads of highish rep users hanging out on the Channel Islands.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: i worked with the data i had. 538 users identified themselves as being from the UK. 225 of those did not specify city or "state" (whatever you call them). So that is why the per-capita users from each of the four states is lower than overall per capita for the entire UK.

Comment: Too bad the numbers are biased towards countries with higher populations...

Comment: @Ivo: this is per capita, so it's actually biased toward countries with *small* populations--how else would Bermuda and Isle of Man be on top?

Comment: Ah I accidently opened both version and commented in the wrong one, wooops!

Comment: YEAH COLORADO!!!

Comment: Isle of Man has Jon Skeet in it. That's all there needs to be said.

Answer (score 7):

Vikings strike again!

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a strong relation with "good English speaking countries" and SO country usage. Look at Europe: Esp. England, Ireland but also the (well-known English speaking) Scandinavian countries.

Other countries might prefer Q&A fora in their native language.

Comment: Users per million "fluent" English speakers (writers) might well give very different results.

Answer (score 3):

Given 4M population in Michigan, I suppose that means there are 88 users here.

I propose a party.

Comment: Actually, Wikipedia says 10M in MI. There are 34 Michiganis here with rep >= 1000. But this post made me realize that my per-capita data for the states in the US was very wrong. I've updated my post. MI is now at 3.3988 users per 1M residents, ranked 33 in the nation.

Comment: Oh sure, cut us down to barely a roomfull of users.  I see how it is!

Answer (score 1):

Although the population of cities is somewhat subjective, could you do an analysis of per-capita for cities?

Comment: Sorry, I'm done with tedious data gathering for the moment.  You can take the raw data from my other post, and look at the "by city" tab here: http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=t8H6oZuQzJFA9Afdj4z_pZg&gid=3 . If you want to go look up the actual population for each of those cities, and then calculate users/population, feel free.  But there are 743 cities represented, which is a lot to look up.