# Updated statistics about where our users are from

Tags: feature-request, statistics, blog, demographics

This [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-come-from/) contains a breakdown of SO users by country, but it's quite old.

It is possible to make another one with updated data? Thanks.

**EDIT**: this was just posted on https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/ :)

Comment: If you want to use OData and ther Profile-Information, [please see this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60876/is-there-a-way-to-find-stackoverflow-users-based-on-an-area).

Comment: There's also [Where in the world do StackOverflow users say they are from?
](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stackoverflow-users-say-they-are-from)

Comment: And [What countries have the most Stack Overflow users per capita?
](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25838/what-countries-have-the-most-stack-overflow-users-per-capita)