# The user survey results show where developers live, but it's just a population map

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey, demographics

The [infographic of the SO user survey results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/?cb=1) was quite intriguing, but one of the charts annoyed me as it showed very little real data. I don't need to be told there are more devolpers in California than in Utah - there are so many fewer residents in Utah that it's obvious. Compare the following two graphs:

## Population map:

[image: Population map]

## Survey results:

[image: Survey results]

Can we have a map of the *per capita* results? I think they would be more interesting and informative.

Comment: At least there are no developers in Arizona

Comment: I smiled a bit seeing Colorado: a patch of light orange in the middle of nothingness.

Comment: Ah, so *you're* the guy who submitted 270 responses, eh @Null?

Comment: I feel like a lemming for posting links to xkcd, but [relevant](http://xkcd.com/1138/).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: The correlation between SO users and subscribers to Martha Stewart is alarming, to say the least. This may explain the waffles and unicorns.

Comment: @JoshCaswell More disturbing than the correlations between SO users and consumers of furry pornography?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: You can pry my racoon suit out of my cold dead hands! And let me add this: can you name any furry aficiando who has gone to jail for tax evasion?

Comment: Oh, if only [there was a site on SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) where they could've asked if their junk statistics and visualizations made any sense...

Comment: @random, Arizona actually ranks in the top 30th percentile (16th place) when you normalize for population. And @ Null, it turns out Colorado is a bright spot even after normalization, ranking at 6th place.

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25838/what-countries-have-the-most-stack-overflow-users-per-capita

Comment: Why is there zero mention of non-USA users? Most SE users are not from the USA.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are the per capita results (full data and sources listed below). Update: @Pang has produced a visualization: http://jsfiddle.net/T8m4s/embedded/result/ -- Snapshot here:

[image: developers per capita]

Note that California doesn't even make it onto the top 10 (it ranks at 13th place), and New York just barely makes cut for top 10.

1. Washington DC [8.2%]
2. Washington State [4.8%]
3. Massachusetts [4.5%]
4. Utah [3.8%]
5. Oregon [3.4%]
6. Colorado [3.3%]
7. New Hampshire [3.2%]
8. Minnesota [3.0%]
9. Rhode Island [3.0%]
10. New York [2.8%]
11. Virginia [2.8%]
12. Maryland [2.5%]
13. California [2.5%]
14. Nebraska [2.4%]
15. Wisconsin [2.3%]
16. Arizona [2.2%]
17. Pennsylvania [2.2%]
18. Idaho [2.0%]
19. Kansas [1.9%]
20. New Jersey [1.9%]
21. Iowa [1.9%]
22. Connecticut [1.8%]
23. Illinois [1.8%]
24. Ohio [1.7%]
25. Wyoming [1.7%]
26. Missouri [1.7%]
27. Michigan [1.7%]
28. Alaska [1.6%]
29. Maine [1.5%]
30. North Carolina [1.5%]
31. Montana [1.4%]
32. Georgia [1.3%]
33. Florida [1.3%]
34. Texas [1.3%]
35. Vermont [1.3%]
36. Tennessee [1.3%]
37. Indiana [1.2%]
38. South Dakota [1.2%]
39. North Dakota [1.1%]
40. Nevada [1.1%]
41. South Carolina [1.0%]
42. Oklahoma [0.9%]
43. New Mexico [0.9%]
44. Alabama [0.8%]
45. Arkansas [0.8%]
46. Kentucky [0.8%]
47. Delaware [0.7%]
48. Louisiana [0.6%]
49. Mississippi [0.5%]
50. Hawaii [0.4%]
51. West Virginia [0.3%]
52. Puerto Rico [0.2%]

Note this is 52 items because it includes Washington DC and Puerto Rico -- which, interestingly, rank at the very top and very bottom respectively. My theory on DC is that it is all city so white collar skilled professions will be more common, and my theory on Puerto Rico is the language barrier, Spanish being the dominant official language there.

---

Raw stack exchange data from https://www.surveymonkey.com/sr.aspx?sm=vU4rF_2bPVQaftSo1s69bGGbvMPXp7ktcfSHiDFP_2bM5qw_3d:

```
Alabama - 20, Alaska - 6, Arizona - 74, Arkansas - 12, California - 471, Colorado - 87, Connecticut - 33, Delaware - 3, Florida - 126, Georgia - 66, Hawaii - 3, Idaho - 16, Illinois - 114, Indiana - 41, Iowa - 29, Kansas - 28, Kentucky - 17, Louisiana - 13, Maine - 10, Maryland - 75, Massachusetts - 149, Michigan - 85, Minnesota - 82, Mississippi - 7, Missouri - 52, Montana - 7, Nebraska - 22, Nevada - 15, New Hampshire - 21, New Jersey - 85, New Mexico - 9, New York - 280, North Carolina - 72, North Dakota - 4, Ohio - 101, Oklahoma - 18, Oregon - 66, Pennsylvania - 141, Puerto Rico - 3, Rhode Island - 16, South Carolina - 24, South Dakota - 5, Tennessee - 41, Texas - 169, Utah - 55, Vermont - 4, Virginia - 114, Washington - 168, Washington DC - 26, West Virginia - 3, Wisconsin - 66, Wyoming - 5
```

Raw census projection data from http://www.census.gov/popest/data/state/totals/2012/tables/NST-EST2012-01.csv:

```
Alabama - 4822023, Alaska - 731449, Arizona - 6553255, Arkansas - 2949131, California - 38041430, Colorado - 5187582, Connecticut - 3590347, Delaware - 917092, Florida - 19317568, Georgia - 9919945, Hawaii - 1392313, Idaho - 1595728, Illinois - 12875255, Indiana - 6537334, Iowa - 3074186, Kansas - 2885905, Kentucky - 4380415, Louisiana - 4601893, Maine - 1329192, Maryland - 5884563, Massachusetts - 6646144, Michigan - 9883360, Minnesota - 5379139, Mississippi - 2984926, Missouri - 6021988, Montana - 1005141, Nebraska - 1855525, Nevada - 2758931, New Hampshire - 1320718, New Jersey - 8864590, New Mexico - 2085538, New York - 19570261, North Carolina - 9752073, North Dakota - 699628, Ohio - 11544225, Oklahoma - 3814820, Oregon - 3899353, Pennsylvania - 12763536, Rhode Island - 1050292, South Carolina - 4723723, South Dakota - 833354, Tennessee - 6456243, Texas - 26059203, Utah - 2855287, Vermont - 626011, Virginia - 8185867, Washington - 6897012, Washington DC - 632323, West Virginia - 1855413, Wisconsin - 5726398, Wyoming - 576412, Puerto Rico - 3667084
```

Per-capita * 1,000,000 (i.e. number of SO responses per million state residents):

```
Alabama - 4.147636790616718, Alaska - 8.202895895681038, Arizona - 11.292098354176666, Arkansas - 4.068995239614653, California - 12.381238034427202, Colorado - 16.770819237170613, Connecticut - 9.191312148937136, Delaware - 3.2712094315510334, Florida - 6.5225601897713, Georgia - 6.653262694500826, Hawaii - 2.1546879185930172, Idaho - 10.026771479851202, Illinois - 8.854193567428373, Indiana - 6.271669766299228, Iowa - 9.43339147338515, Kansas - 9.702329078746528, Kentucky - 3.8809108269421957, Louisiana - 2.8249244387038117, Maine - 7.5233675797025565, Maryland - 12.745211496588617, Massachusetts - 22.419014694836584, Michigan - 8.600314063233556, Minnesota - 15.244075306475628, Mississippi - 2.345116763363648, Missouri - 8.635022188685863, Montana - 6.964197062899633, Nebraska - 11.856482666630738, Nevada - 5.436888418014078, New Hampshire - 15.900442032288499, New Jersey - 9.588711942684322, New Mexico - 4.315433235932407, New York - 14.307422880052544, North Carolina - 7.383045635527954, North Dakota - 5.717324063645251, Ohio - 8.748963226201845, Oklahoma - 4.718440188527899, Oregon - 16.92588488397947, Pennsylvania - 11.04709541305795, Puerto Rico - 0.8180887048128703, Rhode Island - 15.233858774512232, South Carolina - 5.080738222795875, South Dakota - 5.999851203690148, Tennessee - 6.350442509676293, Texas - 6.485232875310883, Utah - 19.262511964646638, Vermont - 6.389664079385186, Virginia - 13.926441756261127, Washington - 24.358374322097742, Washington DC - 41.118225969955226, West Virginia - 1.6168906868713326, Wisconsin - 11.525569825918492, Wyoming - 8.674350985059299
```

Percentage based on last result set (i.e. percentage of SO respondents normalized to population size):

```
Alabama - 0.824721537170129, Alaska - 1.6310745742340413, Arizona - 2.2453356411538934, Arkansas - 0.8090843480665424, California - 2.4619016030822145, Colorado - 3.3347316843587764, Connecticut - 1.827612557886197, Delaware - 0.6504515720608812, Florida - 1.2969544194811282, Georgia - 1.322943476877953, Hawaii - 0.4284409706182859, Idaho - 1.9937363865669924, Illinois - 1.7605794571625484, Indiana - 1.2470670387501877, Iowa - 1.8757479281354774, Kansas - 1.9292238341738914, Kentucky - 0.7716853968642833, Louisiana - 0.5617116789849995, Maine - 1.4959562729950668, Maryland - 2.534274563482699, Massachusetts - 4.457826274179643, Michigan - 1.7100977237018886, Minnesota - 3.031151919554754, Mississippi - 0.4663060917725937, Missouri - 1.7169991328706176, Montana - 1.3847700743382283, Nebraska - 2.3575585577735083, Nevada - 1.0810780210241895, New Hampshire - 3.1616647398393933, New Jersey - 1.9066320538825035, New Mexico - 0.8580864023448015, New York - 2.8449067230945992, North Carolina - 1.4680544736474985, North Dakota - 1.1368402124642574, Ohio - 1.7396553181517227, Oklahoma - 0.9382208331577232, Oregon - 3.365565140867746, Pennsylvania - 2.1966189351328276, Puerto Rico - 0.16266983061322227, Rhode Island - 3.0291204509448555, South Carolina - 1.0102606492793207, South Dakota - 1.1930182793955861, Tennessee - 1.262730314317618, Texas - 1.289532207336161, Utah - 3.8301831330026452, Vermont - 1.2705291826596392, Virginia - 2.7691519369578557, Washington - 4.84345108504518, Washington DC - 8.17600195956597, West Virginia - 0.3215046639882644, Wisconsin - 2.291759414685823, Wyoming - 1.7248193223031953
```

Previous result set sorted by percentage descending:

```
Washington DC - 8.17600195956597, Washington - 4.84345108504518, Massachusetts - 4.457826274179643, Utah - 3.8301831330026452, Oregon - 3.365565140867746, Colorado - 3.3347316843587764, New Hampshire - 3.1616647398393933, Minnesota - 3.031151919554754, Rhode Island - 3.0291204509448555, New York - 2.8449067230945992, Virginia - 2.7691519369578557, Maryland - 2.534274563482699, California - 2.4619016030822145, Nebraska - 2.3575585577735083, Wisconsin - 2.291759414685823, Arizona - 2.2453356411538934, Pennsylvania - 2.1966189351328276, Idaho - 1.9937363865669924, Kansas - 1.9292238341738914, New Jersey - 1.9066320538825035, Iowa - 1.8757479281354774, Connecticut - 1.827612557886197, Illinois - 1.7605794571625484, Ohio - 1.7396553181517227, Wyoming - 1.7248193223031953, Missouri - 1.7169991328706176, Michigan - 1.7100977237018886, Alaska - 1.6310745742340413, Maine - 1.4959562729950668, North Carolina - 1.4680544736474985, Montana - 1.3847700743382283, Georgia - 1.322943476877953, Florida - 1.2969544194811282, Texas - 1.289532207336161, Vermont - 1.2705291826596392, Tennessee - 1.262730314317618, Indiana - 1.2470670387501877, South Dakota - 1.1930182793955861, North Dakota - 1.1368402124642574, Nevada - 1.0810780210241895, South Carolina - 1.0102606492793207, Oklahoma - 0.9382208331577232, New Mexico - 0.8580864023448015, Alabama - 0.824721537170129, Arkansas - 0.8090843480665424, Kentucky - 0.7716853968642833, Delaware - 0.6504515720608812, Louisiana - 0.5617116789849995, Mississippi - 0.4663060917725937, Hawaii - 0.4284409706182859, West Virginia - 0.3215046639882644, Puerto Rico - 0.16266983061322227
```

Comment: That's quite interesting about D.C. Everyone at Fort Meade is an avid SO user, I guess.

Comment: Massachusetts is #3 just because of MIT. And Tufts. And Northeaster. And UMass Amherst. And UMass Lowell. And.... [oh, screw it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_engineering_schools_in_Massachusetts)

Comment: I find it interesting that you associated West Virginia with the "Deep South."  I grew up in WV and lived further *north* than Philadelphia and about half of the state of New Jersey.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan, yeah I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote that -- I spent a large amount of time growing up in North Carolina, which is also considerably south of West Virgina, and I don't associate NC with the deep south either. I think it must have been a brain fart on my part (and a misguided attempt at tasteless humor). Will edit it out of my answer.

Comment: Visualization based on your last data: http://jsfiddle.net/T8m4s/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you, @Pang! I've added that to my answer (with attribution, of course).

Comment: Something that I didn't notice before that really pops out in the visualization is the relative low value for Nevada compared to all the surrounding states. I wonder what that's about. West Virginia also seems relatively low compared to surrounding states.

Comment: Wow, that's *very nice* @Pang!

Comment: another visualization I made before I saw @Pang's: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cESoM.png

Comment: @Jake223, also very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Using the data compiled by Ben Lee, I wrote a program to make this graph:
[image]
The two blobs at the bottom are AK and HI; the blob on the right is DC. I did it using this python program:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image


def floodfill(img, seed, color,state,n):
    im = img.load()
    work = [seed]
    start_color = im[seed]
    while work:
        x, y = work.pop()
        im[x, y] = color
        for dx, dy in ((-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)):
            nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
            if nx>=0 and ny>=0 and nx<img.size[0] and ny<img.size[1] and im[nx, ny] == start_color:
                work.append((nx, ny))

            n+=1

USA_MAP = Image.open('map.png')#.convert('2')
POINT_STATE = {
'AR':(359,253),'AZ':(133,221),'AL':(425,267),'CA':(10,125),
'CO':(195,186),'CT':(557,113),'DE':(540,162),'FL':(499,334),
'GA':(468,264),'IA':(333,144),'ID':(119,109),'IL':(387,176),
'IN':(421,169),'KS':(292,196),'KY':(422,199),'LA':(354,301),
'MD':(520,157),'MZ':(495,159),'MY':(540,179),'MA':(569,97),
'ME':(575,60),'MI':(425,126),'MJ':(392,78),'MN':(326,80),
'MO':(349,196),'MS':(385,288),'MT':(152,59),'NE':(281,161),
'NC':(524,220),'ND':(269,70),'NM':(195,246),'NJ':(544,134),
'NV':(67,151),'NY':(537,100),'OH':(448,159),'OK':(303,247),
'OR':(70,70),'PA':(503,139),'RI':(569,107),'SC':(494,242),
'SD':(265,108),'TN':(417,232),'TX':(300,300),'UT':(137,183),
'VA':(510,183),'WA':(80,30),'WI':(384,104),'WV':(485,173),'DC':(584,198),
'WY':(190,132),'NH':(560,80),'VT':(545,80),'HI':(177,350),'AK':(83,350)
}
painted_map = USA_MAP#.convert('L')
data = {
'AL': 0.8247215372,'AK': 1.6310745742,'AZ': 2.2453356412,'AR': 0.8090843481,
'CA': 2.4619016031,'CO': 3.3347316844,'CT': 1.8276125579,'DE': 0.6504515721,
'FL': 1.2969544195,'GA': 1.3229434769,'HI': 0.4284409706,'ID': 1.9937363866,
'IL': 1.7605794572,'IN': 1.2470670388,'IA': 1.8757479281,'KS': 1.9292238342,
'KY': 0.7716853969,'LA': 0.561711679,'ME': 1.495956273,'MD': 2.5342745635,
'MA': 4.4578262742,'MI': 1.7100977237,'MN': 3.0311519196,'MS': 0.4663060918,
'MO': 1.7169991329,'MT': 1.3847700743,'NE': 2.3575585578,'NV': 1.081078021,
'NH': 3.1616647398,'NJ': 1.9066320539,'NM': 0.8580864023,'NY': 2.8449067231,
'NC': 1.4680544736,'ND': 1.1368402125,'OH': 1.7396553182,'OK': 0.9382208332,
'OR': 3.3655651409,'PA': 2.1966189351,#'PR': 0.1626698306,
'RI': 3.0291204509,
'SC': 1.0102606493,'SD': 1.1930182794,'TN': 1.2627303143,'TX': 1.2895322073,
'UT': 3.830183133,'VT': 1.2705291827,'VA': 2.769151937,'WA': 4.843451085,
'DC': 6.1760019596,'WV': 0.321504664,'WI': 2.2917594147,'WY': 1.7248193223
}
data['MJ']=data['MI']
data['MY']=data['MI']
data['MZ']=data['MD']
# Normalize data based on the minimum weight being 0+eps and maximum 30.
G=170
n=0
for k, v in data.items():
    print k
    v = (v-data['WV'])/(data['DC']-data['WV'])
    color = v*4
    if color<1:
         R,G,B=255,255,254
    else:
         v=(v-1.0/4)*4.0/3
         R=240
         G=230-int(120*v)
         B=210-int(180*v)
    floodfill(painted_map, POINT_STATE[k], (R,G,B),k,n)
    n+=1
floodfill(painted_map,(0,0),(220,230,250),'up_left',1)
floodfill(painted_map,(0,300),(220,230,250),'down_left',1)
floodfill(painted_map,(300,0),(220,230,250),'up_right',1)
floodfill(painted_map,(575,350),(220,230,250),'down_right',1)
painted_map.save('out.png')
painted_map.show()
```