# In 2013 and future StackOverflow survey results, show per capita maps

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-developer-survey

So I noticed that SO is [soliciting question suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209790/suggest-a-question-for-the-2013-stack-overflow-user-survey?newsletter=1&nlcode=42503%7C5b01) for the 2013 survey. Well, I don't have a question suggestion, but I do have a survey-related suggestion.

In 2012, the infographic for the survey results included a map of U.S. states showing how many users lived in each state. This is an almost entirely useless graph because it is essentially equivalent to a population [heatmap](http://xkcd.com/1138/). In 2012, this was [pointed out after the fact](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165122/the-user-survey-results-show-where-developers-live-but-its-just-a-population-m). My question isn't really a duplicate of that one though, because I'm asking to change this for the 2013 and onward.

The results for the 2013 survey (and future surveys) should normalize the results according to population size, and show per capita maps. They are much more illuminating. Compare:

2012 general population:

[image: 2012 general population]

2012 SO developer location, original results:

[image: 2012 SO developer location, original results]

2012 SO developer location, per capita results:

[image: 2012 SO developer location, per capita results]

<sub>Note: all graphs copied from [The user survey results show where developers live, but it's just a population map](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165122/the-user-survey-results-show-where-developers-live-but-its-just-a-population-m).</sub>

Comment: Or, for the 80% of Stack Overflow visitors that _don't_ live in the US you could do the same thing for the entire world and maybe count the US as one entity? India has almost as many users now, [according to Alexa](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com).

Comment: One fine day someone in the US will discover the rest of the world.

Comment: Ooh, just noticed that the UK has more per-capita visitors than the US according to that Alexa thing... can we have the UK split by county please? You'll have to determine the difference between a county, a metropolitan county, a ceremonial county, a unitary authority, a borough, a unitary council... there's probably more. I'm not certain and I live here :-).

Comment: I like that Alexa's "top keyword searches leading to SO" list contains "jquery" twice.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards. Do you know much about the Northern Ireland counties? They have two completely different sets up there: the traditional ones (used for sporting purposes), and the administrative ones. They have nothing to do with each other. The borders are completely unrelated. (The Republic of Ireland also has slight differences, especially in Dublin and Tipperary, but nothing so extreme.)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, I'm completely on board with the collecting and reporting being more world-wide, but I see that as an orthogonal issue to this one, which is just about how results should be reported -- raw numbers vs per capita. If you're concerned that SO is not collecting the right stats, it's probably better to address it on either the survey question suggestions post or as a new meta post, rather than commenting here.