# How many users does SO get from different countries?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics, location

Is there a breakdown of SO user distribution? I would like to know how many users SO gets from different countries. This query is not supported in the JSON API unfortunately.

Comment: We don't have the information, not directly. You can try http://quantcast.com

Comment: Specifically, the [quantcast breakdown of visitors at stackoverflow.com by country](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#!countries).

Comment: @Oded this is telling about *visitors*, OP here is after *users*.

Comment: The proportions should be roughly the same.

Comment: Or perhaps more interesting, *[What countries have the most Stack Overflow users per capita?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25838/what-countries-have-the-most-stack-overflow-users-per-capita)*.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing official, but looks like the API does give the users location as someone wrote this: [StackMaps - Interactive Maps of Stack Exchange Communities](https://stackapps.com/questions/3367/stackmaps-interactive-maps-of-stack-exchange-communities)

Direct link to the external site: http://johndbritton.com/stackmaps/

Screenshot just in case:

[image]

Comment: Amazing stuff. My "Hello world" looked different.