# Ads on Stack Overflow for jobs outside of US

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, advertising, jobs

I'm based outside of the US, and yet the ads that I see on Stack Overflow are always for U.S.-based jobs.
Is this because SO does not have advertisers outside of the US, or because SO has some setting (that I have have not discovered) that allows you to set your locale?

Please, get programmer job ads from other countries onto SO as well!

Comment: +1 : Me too! I would like to see jobs from my country as well.

Comment: I've seen UK jobs advertised

Comment: @Jojas: ["The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) refers to **Stack Overflow**, not Meta. There's nothing wrong with the `[jobs]` tag here...

Comment: @TheEstablishment sorry for the misunderstand doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you are referring to these job ads:

[obligatory hand drawn circle screenshot http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6389/jobs.jpg](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6389/jobs.jpg)

If so, you can go to http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/ to see all of the jobs. Most of them are US based, which is why you see US-based jobs so often. There is no setting to change your locale.

I agree it would be nice to see more jobs outside the US, but it is really down to who pays to advertise their job vacancy and where the job is.

Additionally, if you read the jobs board [FAQ](http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/default.asp?pg=pgFAQ), it says that the advert is only shown for 21 days, meaning that even if there are jobs outside of the US, they soon disappear from the listings.

Comment: You can change your locale once you get to http://jobs.stackoverflow.com, but that won't affect the ads

Comment: @ChrisF: that looks like just filtering search results, not changing locale. Still doesn't affect the ad though.

Comment: @adrianbanks: +1 Yup, those are the ads I am referring to. Any stats on the profile of who uses SO - i.e. how many of us are really not based in US?

Comment: @ChrisF, @adrianbanks: I just took a look at jobs.stackoverflow.com, and it looks like at the moment, if you're not based in US or select Eurpoean countries, there just aren't any listings. Eek!

Comment: @bguiz: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stackoverflow-users-say-they-are-from has data from October 2009 showing where users report to be from.

Comment: @adrianbanks - true, but the locale is stored in a cookie as it remembers it between sessions.