# feature-request tag shown at the end of tag list. [feature-request] tag was replaced with itself

Tags: bug, tags, meta, revisions-list

I saw this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38328/346987) and see that it has [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in the end of tag list (it should in the beginning).

[image: Question with issue]

If I go to revision history I'm also facing some oddities: [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) was replaced by itself two times!

[image: Revision history of question with issue]

How is that possible?

Comment: Technically, edit four was a rollback, not an edit. The order is somewhat odd, though... they're supposed to automagically rank themselves by popularity.

Comment: @Catija Yes, but edit 3 where tag is replaced with itself is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: I *think* I've seen that before in the case of someone removing a tag and then adding it back in, either within the same edit (before hitting the submit button) or just within the edit window of five minutes... though, that was a while back, I'm not sure if the grace period existed then.

Comment: So the required tags weren't always so heavily used (before they were required, presumably)... ? Or was this from when the tag class was changed?

Comment: @animuson Can you please elaborate why order of feature-request tag was incorrect? I didn't found this info elsewhere.

Comment: @animuson Ah, OK...I was inferring too much into this question.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov That info was just edited into the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Vadim At the time the question was posted, we didn't auto-sort tags - they were just whatever order you entered them. But this can also occur at any point in time, where one tag ends up becoming more popular than another tag (especially if you use multiple newer tags on a question). They'll get reordered on edit.

Comment: @animuson Maybe to resolve this for all such questions we should force order for every question regardless of date? I mean that if there are plenty of other questions with this issue, maybe it would be better to fix tag order in database then manually edit every question with this issue?

Comment: @Vadim Eh, it's not really that big of an issue, and tag orders can always change at any time. E.g. if for some reason the revisions-list tag became more used than the meta tag, the tags on your question here would get reordered on an edit. But... there's no inherent benefit from explicitly making that edit just to reorder tags.