# Should votes count after a question has been closed?

Tags: bug, voting, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is allowing voting and accepting answers on closed questions best practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24845/is-allowing-voting-and-accepting-answers-on-closed-questions-best-practice)

I'm curious what people think about being able to vote on a question that has been closed?  Should it be allowed, or once a question is closed should all voting cease?

Case in point:
[When's the best day and best time to post a question to Stackoverflow.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42572/whens-the-best-day-and-best-time-to-post-a-question-to-stackoverflow-com/42578#42578)

Question closed and some tool (I won't mention names) makes a comment after its been closed.  I retort in jest and apparently I hurt her feelings and as a retaliation she down-votes my answer.

So what do you think, should voting continue on closed questions?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24845/is-allowing-voting-and-accepting-answers-on-closed-questions-best-practice
and see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2700/prevent-upvotes-for-questions-closed-as-duplicates

Comment: Apparently I didnt look hard enough.. please downvote, delete, or close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer isn't always the best or even correct. The community needs a way to say which answer is best even after an answer is accepted.

Comment: +1 + accept to help boost your rep

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the community still needs to rate questions and answers after they're closed.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the question has not been deleted and therefore is still viewable by the world at large, I believe there is still value in capturing votes, since it will still affect how answers are sorted for that question.