# Portuguese programming site: one of SE or plagiarism of SE sites?

Tags: discussion

I am commited to [SO in portuguese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) at Area 51. Today i got a email, from someone who "found me at SO", suggesting me to join a Q&A site for portuguese programmers.

The layout/concept is same SE's but is [**this**](http://nukson.pt/) the Area 51 beta (I don't think so), another SE site? or just a attempt to copy the SE concept?

### Update:

The "real" portuguese Stackoverflow is now online: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Doesn't 'plagiate' mean 'to visit a beach'?

Comment: @Rosinante, maybe also. Changed to *plagiarism* to be more clear, thanks.

Comment: [We discussed nukson some time ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199314/is-nukson-com-part-of-stackexchange-sites).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a clone - this is most certainly not a Stack Exchange site. Most probably using one of the [many clone backends](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).

We are, in fact, working on a Portuguese Stack Overflow - it will be our first localized Stack Overflow site.

And just so you have a flavor of what it would be like (though I don't know if we will have the Stack Overflow theme or not):

[image]

---

Update:

The Portuguese site is now in private beta! Once it goes into public beta, all will be able to participate (though I can imagine the community will not allow English...):

http://br.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Was not aware of "the clones". That explains it.

Comment: @Sergio - we don't have a timeframe for launch yet, possibly early next year.

Comment: No problem, I'm a happy SO user, but sure many portuguese non english fluent programmers will be happy, when its done. I see you have a head start in score already :)

Comment: @Sergio - That's just a dev box with an existing database (all questions are in English...).

Comment: Back to the clone again, feels strange to see a "exact copy" of the concept. I call it plagiate. (btw if you want to delete this question, to not give the site more views please do that)

Comment: @Sergio - It is a valid questions, and people can copy SE concepts if they want to (but of course, they keep chasing our lead...). Once the official site goes live, what will happen to the clone?

Comment: This is an amazing development, very interested to see how it'll play out. Can you share some pointers as to what factors lead to Portuguese / Brazil to be chosen as the target for the first internationalized Stack Overflow? After all, Brazil doesn't seem to play a very big role in the [user map...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-say-they-are-from)

Comment: @perhapsPekka - I probably don't have all the details, but: Brazil is huge and growing in tech. We do have lots of users, but it is also a country where English is not common and many developers are not fluent enough to participate. I may be mistaken, but I believe that it was the first [language proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) that got to the commitment stage in area51.

Comment: @Oded interesting! And makes sense to pick such a market over one that has a big overlap with English-language SO.

Comment: @perhapsPekka - It helps that Portugal and a few other countries also use Portuguese. Not sure what the next one would be, but probably one where English is not very commonly used (and seeing as we already got most of the infrastructure work done for this one, the next ones will end up "just" being translation jobs).

Comment: @Oded yeah, great to see multi-language ability come to the platform. I always keep thinking there's a huge programmer population in France and Germany that speaks English, but isn't confident enough about it to participate on a daily basis, hence major untapped potential. Then there's places like Russia and China... well, I'm sure we'll see which way it goes!

Comment: @perhapsPekka - There are a few other language proposals on area51 that are in the committed stage.

Comment: @perhapsPekka and Oded, Just to add some info, and maybe why PT is the first language. The Portuguese speaking coutries are: Portugal, Brazil, East Timor (near Indonesia!), Mozambique, Angola, Guiné, Cape Verde and S. Tomé & Principe. Total population = 258 millions. It is known that Brazil is not so fluent in english... and they are 201M!

Comment: Just updating: The Portuguese SO is now online! http://br.stackoverflow.com/