# Is nukson.com part of stackexchange sites?

Tags: discussion

Today I got an E-Mail from [nukson.com](http://nukson.com/) about their new site. They claim to get my E-Mail ID from github. Then, I visited the site and found it a copy of stackoverflow.

So my question is: Is this site is a part of stackexchange or who owns it?

Comment: There are loads of copies of stack overflow, some legitimate,  some without attribution

Comment: @RichardTingle: I don't think that it scrapped content.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I was taking VarunAgw's word for it to an extent what the site actually is, clicking on links to dodgy websites isn't high on my priorities for the day

Comment: `nukson.com` has no affiliation with Stack Exchange, and is not one of our sites. It appears to be a Q&A site for PHP programmers that (obviously) wants more users.

Comment: @TimPost: Can you give me a hand? It seems like it scraps content, but it's...different: [On nukson.com](http://nukson.com/questions/285/randomized-string-in-php) and on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator). It looks like they're copying content by hand...

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby They do appear to be rewriting some content, but _not_ the code snippets, this is getting sort of interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I broke and had a look and found the same thing, content that says the same thing but in a slightly different way to stack overflow

Comment: Brought this to the attention of our scraper department, even though they don't _technically_ appear to be scraping, unless you count short snippets of code. I don't think there's anything actionable here, but I have made folks on our team aware of it.

Comment: Given that they have only 90 questions I guess rewriting by hand would be plausible

Comment: @TimPost: It looks like [their mod](http://nukson.com/users/284/eric-johnson) is [copying questions](http://nukson.com/questions/297/adding-a-time-interval-in-php) from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036492/whats-the-best-way-of-adding-a-time-interval-in-php) to get a higher search ranking or populate the site with questions or something. Pretty interesting, that's kinda new (compared to the 1:1 bot scrapers).

Comment: wait, until when was accept = 25 rep, and question upvotes = 15 rep and public?

Comment: stealing content, doesn't seem very moderatory, we need to send an email to.....  O yeah, right

Comment: @RichardTingle: "Stealing" is not correct, "violating copyright/license" is.

Comment: @JanDvorak: That reminds me...maybe we can send Evan over there? I'm sure he'd love some of these features.

Comment: Is it weird that it's annoying me that it doesn't quite have the same behaviour as stack exchange

Comment: Apparently there anyone can accept answers, no need of OP. The reputation history of the mod is an interesting read. *Daniel Nelson accepted Eric Johnson answer on Dennis Peters question Clearing APC cache entries*

Comment: @Krishnabhadra wait, what? I don't think that was _ever_ possible on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well (silly) people have been asking for moderator accept for quite some time here

Comment: @Krishnabhadra That's actually the utility of these near copies of our engine. They try stuff that we _probably_ wouldn't, albeit on a smaller scale, and we get to eat popcorn and watch how it goes.

Comment: "Nukson the world's #1 question and answer PHP community" PHP is doomed

Comment: @RichardTingle they must be counting from zero. Because, as far as I know, Stack Overflow is better.

Comment: @RichardTingle: I like that they only have ~500 users...but are still #1.

Comment: **Pertinent questioning** badge for asking [first question](http://nukson.com/badges/26/pertinent-questioning).

Comment: "you should not ask subjective questions when ... You provide an answer along with the question"

Comment: also, it must be noted their website is not exactly performant, even when it comes to simple things like loading the "log in to vote" popup.

Comment: Wow! So many comments. I am wondering how can I pronunciate nukson. Should I use the hindi word. http://dict.hinkhoj.com/words/meaning-of-nuksan-in-english.html LOL

Comment: Nuke Nukson! ---

Comment: Wow. That is a pretty blatant design ripoff. Do all OSQA sites look that much like SO?

Comment: Also, pro tip: if the page takes that long to load, it's not a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @nhinkle Maybe some temporary network glitch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then, I visited the site and found it a copy of stackoverflow.

Not, it's not a copy. As it seems some users/mods are copying questions (maybe even answers) from Stack Overflow to populate the site with content and/or to get better searchmachine rankings, but most of the questions seem genuine. Tim Post already notified the appropriate department of Stack Exchange and they're looking into it.

> So my question is: Is this site is a part of stackexchange or who owns it?

Partial whois output of the domain:

```
Domain Name: NUKSON.COM
Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com
Updated Date: 2013-03-16 16:42:21
Creation Date: 2012-03-20 20:53:21
Registrar Expiration Date: 2014-03-20 20:53:21
Registrar: GoDaddy.com, LLC
Registrant Name: Miguel Angelo
[...]    
Name Server: NS1.NUKSON.COM
Name Server: NS2.NUKSON.COM
```

So no, not affiliated with Stack Exchange. They also run on a completely different system, despite that they removed all notices about the underlying engine, I'm 99% sure that they run on [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/).

Comment: It looks similar to stackoverflow site.  How?  Is it something like iframe?

Comment: @user1671639 No, they just duplicated some of our features and styles. There are many 'clones' of Stack Overflow that you can run on your own server. Look up OSQA, Question2answer, etc.

Comment: @TimPost  OSQA, Question2answer, etc never know that site like SE exists..