# Can we make a network wide survey at Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, data-analysis

At any *intellectual community*, it is evident that any participants should have the option of seeing the demographics of the community that they are participating in. This is so that people know the overall composition of their community, and know the following questions:

1. What countries the community comes from (this will help show the focus of the community. For example, if the community is a Humanities-based SE, then, this will show that the community is more focused on the Humanities that come from that area. Also, it helps diversity.)
2. What percentage of the SE holds a degree in the subject of which the SE is about.
3. The average length of time the users have been on the site.
4. Other information that may be useful. (This can probably be decided by the leaders of the specific SE.)

This might also be helpful later on for researchers who want to study intellectual communities (or the intellectual communities based on the subject which is relevant), so that they can use information for their theses.

Can we create such a survey for network sites?

Comment: Are you asking *whether* there is such a census ([[tag:support]]) or *for* there to be such a census ([[tag:feature-request]])? As is, the text of your question and the tags disagree

Comment: I'm asking for that feature to be there if it doesn't exist already

Comment: if(censusDoesntExist) {CreateCensus();} else {break;//do nothing}

Comment: Please edit your question so it matches the tags and clearly asks for it. Right now, your question is not phrased as asking for it to be implemented; it's only asking if it's there.

Comment: There's a SO user survey... I wonder if we could rescope the question to a request for a broader network wide survey....

Comment: @Journeyman Geek, sure, I don’t know much about the SO user survey. If you can, feel free to Edit my question to make it better.

Comment: 'Also, it helps diversity'.....how?  Does diversity need help and, if so, what kind?  What is diversity?

Comment: 'At any Intellectual Community, it is evident that any participants should have the option of seeing the demographics of the community that they are participating in' no.

Comment: 'This is so that people know the overall composition of their community' - my compiler does not care, neither do I.

Comment: Census participation is (as far as I can tell) mandatory and refusal to participate can be fined or result in a criminal record. So no, we should not create a census: If I have to share my demographics or risk a criminal record just to participate here, I'm out.

Comment: Here is your data: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1449532/census

Comment: @MartinJames Diversity in thought, is what I am trying to talk about. Coming from a different part of the world brings new ideas and thoughts into a community (doesn't apply for scientific or mathematical communities of course

Comment: @MartinJames seeing as you are more interested in computer science (as shown by your comment about your compiler), I understand that this would not be relevant to you. (With the slight exception that there are CS languages based off of non-English languages: interesting but irrelevant to you)

Answer (score -1):

From the question comments

> Unexplained downvotes are pointless. Please explain why you are downvoting my question so that I can improve it. – Proud Tamil Indian 13 hours ago

I think that the question has several "problems", and one of them is the unfortunate word choice. In the comments someone already mentioned an opinion about "census", and someone else replaced "census" by "survey".

Another possible thing that might be attracting several downvotes, is the use of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) by one hand because some people think that posts with this tag should include some research, and in this specific case the company already have some surveys, the Stack Overflow Survey, The Loop and maybe others, the user profile has a field for the user location, also there is a dedicated site to query SE network data. On the other hand, there are people that don't like census / surveys, especially as a "feature".

My suggestion is that if you need help to find a feature instead of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) use [support](/questions/tagged/support). If you want to discuss an idea use [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). If you want do to a feature request, follow the guidelines on [How do I write a good feature request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258136/289691)

Related tags

- [survey](/questions/tagged/survey)
- [data-analysis](/questions/tagged/data-analysis)
- [the-loop](/questions/tagged/the-loop)
- [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer)
- [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump)

Related to users' country

- [Filter users by country](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1031/289691)
- [Finding Top Users by country](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207650/289691)

Related to how Meta works

- [How can Meta be made more conducive to discussions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124643/289691)
- [What is a meta for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240440/289691)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try to improve my question, thanks.

Comment: @ProudTamilIndian Sometimes the best is to start from scratch

Comment: I don't think answers should be used to give what is essentially feedback on how to improve the question...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I occasionally allow me to do exceptions on per-site metas and here specially when the comments  haven't enough room for the feedback and when a post will be more convenient than a chat room. Do you have a suggestion of a better way to handle this kind of feedback?

Answer (score -2):

I don't actually think this is that bad an idea.

Newer sites *used* to run limited site satisfaction surveys - but these turned out to be a lot of work. Considering the number of network site - running a network wide survey might be an option

Stack Exchange runs an annual survey focused on [Stack Overflow](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) . It includes geographic and educational demographic information so... 1 and 2.

SE ought to be able to pull information on 'tenture' of users fairly easily, and information on users broad site activity might be useful.

It might also be useful to aggregate and visualise the crossover between our communities in some way, and how experience in the network might reflect activity on newer sites

With something like this - I guess the big question is what's the value of this data. The SO survey began primarily as a tool for marketing as I understand. I'd see this as a useful tool to understanding the community as it is, and to better understand how new and current communities can better serve their user base.

Its also a way to get a gauge of the make-up and sentiments of the community for planning for the coming here.

As a moderator, and a long time user - I actually think an optional SE survey, *not* soft-restricted to just developer types is long overdue.

Comment: I’m not sure why you’re getting such a negative response to this suggestion. Maybe it’s because of negativity toward the annual survey? I don’t fill out that survey because I don’t like the US-centric view of dicing people up by gender identity and race. It’s also not targeted toward the SO community; it samples people who may have never visited SO, even though the method for soliciting participants favors engaged SE users.

Comment: It also won't let you complete if you are not a dev. I try periodically and never actually get past that 

Comment: The question has the word 'diversity' in it.  That makes the proposed census radioactive.  No way would I approach it.

Comment: I'm going to disagree there. Its useful to know what our community is like - and its certainly better than assuming that a certain group of people 'need' something.  Aside from nationality, cultural identity and gender - and I know that there's some controversy around that. If nothing else - It would be useful to know how people use our other sites. That said - we *are* a diverse set of communities with different interests and backgrounds, so I don't think being aware of that should be radioactive at all.

Comment: While a survey *may* be useful for the reasons you mention, the description of your survey and the reasons for it seem far enough removed from the *census* and reasons for that, that the original question proposed.. that I struggle to see this as much of an answer to the Q at all :/ The question seems to suggest just making this data open to basically every internet rando... While I wouldn't mind filling in a survey to improve the community I'm using at times, I don't think a census that hands out the data gathered to random people "for a thesis" or "any participants" would ever be a good idea

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah I agree on that

Comment: @Tinkeringbell For History, there is a field called Historiography, which is about the study of the study of History, if that makes sense. I don't know, but I assume that, there are equivalents in other fields, (such as the study of how people generally study?), and something like this might be helpful to them.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm apolitical

Answer (score -3):

I know for a fact that the Stack Exchange corp has access to the country of origin info, because I've occasionally seen their data scientist write [blog posts about things they've noticed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/) that would have required access to that kind of information.