# Adding companies for users so that we can see from which companies best awnsers come

Tags: feature-request

Would it be nice to sign up as company and that users that work for such a company can link up with this company.

This way you would get rankings of developing companies all over the world with most points etc. Also when someone is looking for a job he could find the company on Stack Overflow and check how the employees discuss on wich level they are etc.

I think this would be a cool feature!

Comment: This is not a freelancing website so this is not a good feature IMO. There is already [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: no but there are many +10 employee companies that have quality developers and contribute many to opensource etc. It would be nice to see these companies and see wich users are connected to this companies... not to gain any work or somethin.. just because its nice to see this..... And careers is for job searching

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you but what of this part of your req `Also when someone is looking for a job he could find the company on stackoverflow and check how the employees discuss on wich level they are etc.`

Comment: Why would Stack Exchange give my company free advertising? It'd be nice to know out who actually works in the same place but I don't see it as something that's necessary.

Comment: Well on careers youll get a job description etc etc. But I think it would also be nice to see what kind of awnsers are placed by the employees of a certain company to see how skilled they are and how they contribute... to get that info about a company you could search it on stackoverflow... not to get a job... but to get to know the company better....

Answer (score 11):

I argue against this point,

This would encourage company sponsored voting rings and sounds anti-community to me.

When I come to Stack Overflow I want to represent myself and not the company I work at.

The less commercial and company interests we have here - the better. The site works best when it's community-driven.

Comment: Why this negative.. these things can happen but you can discourage it,, like how ppl get downvotes now... also i think you only look at the negative aspect of this feature. but there are also positive things like mentioned above.,,,

Comment: @rZaaaa every such decision has pros and cons, I think the abuse potential and negative effect on the site outweight the potential for gain here.

Comment: Well you dont have to connect yourself with a company even if you are working there.. but a benefit would be that as a company there is a controlling factor of the company itself that wants good reputation on the website therfor encouraging employees to help on this website etc etc etc...

Comment: Right, I totally see why you think it'd be a good idea. The problem is that this also encourages a lot of abuse potential (Boss: "Hey, can everyone upvote everyone working at the company? We want to be highly ranked here")

Comment: Thats true but then they have to make spam accounts to do so.. because you could block votes from employees from 1 company... to upvote eachoter.. also new users have to contribute before they can upvote... so these things can be tackled... wow for a developer site you guys really think narrow minded

Comment: @rZaaaa think about .. after your suggestion quiet a bit companies will have policy that all the employee will need to do upvote periodically so they can not be caught by serial voting scripts(this will result in inflation of reputation) .. moreover company will force employees to represent the company views not the individual employee views so new idea will come less(as company genraly play safely as they will think more about reputation) .. i will vote against this idea .. and after all this the company who has more employee will always be on upperside as they will have more upvotes

Answer (score 4):

### Executive Summary

1. This functionality already exists
2. Making it useful would cause more harm than good
3. It doesn't provide the information you think it does

### The Mystical Profile

So you already have this in your profile (though you haven't filled it in):

[image: Magical! Profilesque!]

In the year 2013, most businesses have a website. If employees of companies were to insert their webpage in to that field, you would be able to gather your data, huzzah!

### But Nobody Fills That In!

Right, nobody does. So why would they if we added an additional company field? You can't force people to state their affiliation, and making them do it will not make users happy. I doubt your real name is rZaaaa.

### The Data is Useless for Your Purpose

So let's say we do have a populated field for it. What does this say about the companies they work for? Unless they are only allowed to post during working hours on a work account about work, then a single person may be asking questions about a new technology for a pet project, rather than something appropriate to the type of work they're doing.

Companies that were doing sensitive work would want to hide the technologies their employees are working on lest someone get a reasonable idea of what the company is going to develop.

Companies that don't want their employees working on pet projects can search for employees of their company to see what they are asking about off-hours, and could use that against the employees in further interactions.

Just like [looking at location stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25598/where-in-the-world-do-stack-overflow-users-say-they-are-from/198372#198372), there is a lot of noise in the data anyway, and trying to do that with companies given the far more complicated issues involved is going to be even more of a hurdle if you want to do real analysis.

In short, don't hold your breath.

Comment: upvote for this only **I doubt your real name is rZaaaa**

Answer (score 0):

Do you truly need a new feature for this ? You can already use your profile and the about me section if you want to make it public with which company you are affiliated.

If your questions and answers are of high quality, people will check out your profile.

Comment: no but its for a company overal.... for example i want to work for a company and want to know on wich level their employees are.. then on stack i could seach the company and it would filter out all the questions of their employees so i could check that